# C++ Error-code <U+0013>

Tags: c++

I have a function in C++ that I am testing, and after careful inspection I'm pretty sure everything is correct. However, I'm still getting a mysterious error relating to the "return" statement at the end of the function.

[image]

Where "population" is a real matrix (using the armadillo matrix package).

Comment: Q: How did you manage to insert a [DC3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes)(XOFF) characters into your source code???

Comment: Unfortunately, visual inspection doesn't cut it when the characters are invisible.

Comment: I don't know how they got there! This happened once before and "accidentally" fixed itself. This time I wanted to know exactly what it was though. Anyway it's now fixed. There were some invisible characters for some reason... I deleted them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the error code represents a Unicode value. Check if the file is clean of characters which shouldn't be there (copy paste into notepad and then copy paste back).

Answer (score 1):

You have accidentally managed to enter the [*Device Control 3* character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0013/index.htm) (which has the unicode value `U+0031`) before `return` and after `;`. The character is probably invisible for you, which is why you aren't seeing anything.

Replace those with spaces. You can probably turn your editor into some kind of *"show invisibles"* mode which might help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are used to using Emacs keybindings and tried to Cx-s Cx-c to save and quit in another IDE ie Xcode it will insert odd unicode characters.